# Not able to match using regexpresion

Tags: regex, perl

I need to match a file pattern below. Below is the line I need to search in.

getting apples in a/b/list.txt

Below is the core section of my Perl code

```
my $r_path ="a";
while ($line=<FH1>)
   chomp ;
if($line=~/getting\s*apples\s*in\${r_path}.*\/(\w*)\.txt/)
```

Even though simple it seems strange, when I remove the variable and give the hard-coded value search seems to work.But with r_path variable defined, its not working.

Please let me know the issue. I have also noticed that this pattern is detecting in my vim / regex with variables substituted to their proper values.But in perl ,it seems ,not working even after this substitution.

Comment: This code is not the code you are actually using in your program -- Perl will not even compile it as written here. I can make some guesses as to what's wrong (`\${r_path}` should be `\s*${r_path}`) but it's not clear that's all. Please paste the code exactly as it appears in your program.

Comment: I tried escaping and without escaping $ `if($line=~/getting\s*apples\s*in\s*${r_path}.*\/(\w*)\.txt/)`. Both are not working

Comment: Please paste the code exactly as it appears in your program so we can give you better advice.

Answer (score 2):

`$` shouldn't be escaped —you don't want its special meaning— and there's a missing space before the `$`.

```
my $r_path = "a";
my $line = 'getting apples in a/b/list.txt';
if ($line =~ /getting\s*apples\s*in\s*${r_path}.*\/(\w*)\.txt/) {
   print "<<$1>>\n";   # list
}
```

Comment: I tried escaping and without escaping $   `if($line=~/getting\s*apples\s*in\s*${r_path}.*\/(\w*)\.txt/)`

Comment: Even this is not working with perl, even though they work in regexr ,vim `($line=~ m/getting\s*apples\s*in\s*.*\/(\w*)\.txt/`

Comment: nope .*\/ means it will take the last /

Comment: My test was bad, and I believed you when you said it didn't work. The code in the comment work fine.

Comment: I'm trying to use a variable in the pattern match expression and not hard coded value.Something like $r_path as in my original post

Comment: @user274739 This is unlikely to help unless you show the code you are actually using in your program.

Comment: @user274739 - copy and paste ikegami's code. Run it with `use strict` and `use warnings` and see if it works

Comment: @FlyingFrog, It will. The actual thing to do is find out in what way what he has differs from what he said he has. Is the code different than what he says he's using? Does `$line` contain what he says it does? Does `$r_path` contain what he says it does? Is it true that the pattern isn't matching?